# Load page within the page

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I'm a beginner in PHP and Javascript..

I found a link from http://cmichaelis.whsites.net/whblog/jquery-extjs-1/example2

Inside it there is a code saying :

```
function addPanel(location)
{
 tabpanel.add({
       autoLoad: {url: location},
       title: 'More Information...',
       closable:true,
       autoScroll:true
 }).show();
}
```

how to use :

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);"
   onclick="addPanel('loadpage.php?a=http://www.google.com')">
   head over to Google
</a>
```

What I want to ask is.. what is the code for loadpage.php?

Answer (score 1):

The PHP page does not echo out the contents of google.com as suggested in the other answer. It outputs an iframe that points to Google:

```
<iframe src="http://www.google.com" width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="no"></iframe>
```

Comment: So what's the point? That could just as easily be done in JS without the extra roundtrip to the server.

Comment: I don't know what the point is, I can't see what it achieves.

Comment: It allows you to call your site "Ajax"!

Comment: Some browsers don't allow cross-site content. Perhaps this (since it is from an HTML document and not dynamically requested) was an attempt to circumvent that restriction.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `loadpage.php` could be in use to echo out the contents of `www.google.com`, using [file_get_contents](http://ie.php.net/file_get_contents).

**loadpage.php**:

```
<?php
    // Simplified output - should sanitise $_REQUEST params etc first..
    echo file_get_contents($_REQUEST['a']);
?>
```

`loadpage` is effectively acting as a proxy, allowing your javascript to call pages which are not on your own domain.

As @annakata points out in the comments, the code above is obscenely dangerous as-is. The code is an illustration of the basic idea behind a proxy file - in production, this file would need to make sure that the `$_REQUEST` parameters were sanitised, e.g. only accept values from a whitelist.

The [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) is a security element of javascript that stops you from pulling content from outside your domain on to your page using javascript.

Some sites get around this by calling a proxy page on their own server (`loadpage` in this instance) which effectively just prints out the content of a target url. As this proxy page is on your server, this by-passes the same origin security issue, and still makes available the content of a page from another domain - here `www.google.com`

---

Oops, I somewhat foolishly didn't RTFA, but just the code in the question and hypothesised at what it could be doing. [@andynormancx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/564814/load-page-within-the-page/564889#564889) is right in his answer as to what the page linked in the q is actually doing.

Comment: As it stands that's ridiculously dangerous - I hope there's a whitelist or some sanity checking in the php

Comment: Very unsafe code alright, threw it up as an example of what could be going on in the loadpage file, but answer now updated to highlight the dangers if copied and pasted, cheers!